# MCU Package of STM32f1 series for stm32CubeMX

Tags: stm32, stm32cubemx, hal-library

I am trying to download MCU Package of STM32f1 series for stm32CubeMX from the following link:

https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stm32cubef1.html

But the given link sends this messege that the package is not available for downloading. Could you please tell what I should do now.

I have been also trying to download it while generating code in STM32CubeMX software but the following error occurred:

[image]

Comment: You can get STCubeMX to export the Libraries when you generate your code. Have a look under Project Manager _> Code generator and make sure 'Copy all used Libraries into the project folder' is checked.

Comment: @regimon: Yes, this is what I have also done before, but the problem is, in the middle of downloading an error occurs that some files couldn't be downloaded.

Comment: Which version of CubeMX? Have you updated it? If you use CubeIDE, it has integrated CubeMX, does it work via CubeIDE?